# How to combine two if statements to use or operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

My code below tries to determine if either children `H1` or `H2` elements contain text that can be assigned to a variable, and if not defaults to the parent element text:

```
if($(this).children('h1').length){
    markerCon[markerNum] = $(this).children('h1').text();
} else if($(this).children('h2').length){
    markerCon[markerNum] = $(this).children('h2').text();
} else {
    markerCon[markerNum] = $(this).text();
}
```

This works, but I'm trying to improve my code, and from what I understand I can use the **OR** operator to determine the same thing, like so:

```
if($(this).children('h1').length || $(this).children('h2').length){
    // how do I write this part?
} else {
    markerCon[markerNum] = $(this).text();
}
```

The part I don't understand is how to write the then part of the statement, telling the variable which *H* element to grab text from. Can someone help?

Comment: I think you're only complicating your code.

Comment: Am I? I thought using the OR operator would improve my code, but if the consensus is to leave it then I shall! (still learning)

Comment: Your code is fine as it is, since you are assigning something to markerCon depending on only one condition you cannot use an OR

Comment: // how do I write this part?: write the code from the first example :-)  If you have many 'if-else' you can use 'switch' instead.

Comment: Try running through a minifier and see what it outputs: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/code/jsc4292a34710cb10810696b76fabcee61b/default.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test this but i believe it would do the same with shorter code.

```
markerCon[markerNum] = $(this).children('h1').text() || $(this).children('h2').text();
markerCon[markerNum] = markerCon[markerNum] || $(this).text();
```

This does assume that if the `h1` or `h2` exists, the text in them is not empty string.

Comment: Could just do `markerCon[markerNum] = $(this).children('h1, h2').text() || $(this).text();` with those conditions

Comment: @megawac I followed the logic of the `if` in the question. If there is a `h1` the `h2` is not used, but in your example `markerCon[markerNum]` will have the string from both.